# I am beginner to android..I integrated qr scanner into my app..but I want to split string and load to shared preferences

Tags: android

In my app I Integrated qr scanner..In my app activity  I am using OnActivity result Method to displaying Scanned result.. I am scanning ABCDEFGH..but I want to split ABCDEFGH as two string using OnActivityResult method..load that two string to shared preferences..can anyone help me..below is my code

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, 
        data);

                if (scanResult != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, " " + scanResult.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                else
                {
                     Log.d("ScanFragment", "Cancelled scan");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
                            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                        }
```

@Override

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (scanResult != null) {
        String part1 = scanResult.getContents().substring(0, 10),
                part2 = scanResult.getContents().substring(4);
        //  System.out.println(" ");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " " + scanResult.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setCustomerSerialName(part1.toString(), part2.toString());
    } else {

        Log.d("ScanFragment", "Cancelled scan");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


    // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
private void setCustomerSerialName(String cusSno, String passcode) {
    String customerSNo = IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.getString("customerSNo", "null");
    Editor editor = IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("customerSNo", cusSno);
    editor.putString("customerPass", passcode);
    if (customerSNo.equals(cusSno)) {
    } else {
        editor.putBoolean("custSNoAuthStatus", false);
    }
    editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: You can use method - YourString.substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)

Answer (score 0):

**Divide String into parts**

> I want to split ABCDEFGH as two string using OnActivityResult method

According to what you want to split this string.

- If you have any special character in the `String`, then you can do it using `string.split(",")` method (Here `,` is considered as special character which must be present in `string` named variable).
- If you know from what length you have to divide this string then you can do this using `string.substring(startIndex, endIndex)` as first part and `string.substring(endIndex + 1)` as another part.

**Store strings to `SharedPreferences`**

and then you can store it to `SharedPreferences` using `SharedPreferences.Editor` like below

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("part1", part1);
editor.putString("part2", part2);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: thank you.. but..how to write string split code.. inside onActivityresult method

Comment: `String[] parts = scanResult.getContents().split(",");` like this. or `String part1 = scanResult.getContents().substring(0, 3), part2 = scanResult.getContents().substring(4);`

Comment: can you send your emaild

Comment: provide your code where you implemented `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: private void setCustomerSerialName(String cusSno, String passcode) {
              String customerSNo =    IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.getString("customerSNo", "null");
        Editor editor = IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.edit(); editor.putString("customerSNo", cusSno);
        editor.putString("customerPass", passcode);
        if (customerSNo.equals(cusSno)) {
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean("custSNoAuthStatus", false);
        }
        editor.commit();
        LightManager.LightOp lightOp = new LightManager.LightOp();
        lightOp.setToWWWMode();
    }

Comment: I implemented sharedpreferences like this but loading is not happening   i created setcustomerserial name inside onactivityresult and then I am trying to load

Comment: edit your question and add those code..above code is non-readable.

Comment: `IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences` have you declared `SharedPreferences` static in `IHomeActivity` class?

Comment: private void setCustomerSerialName(String cusSno, String passcode){
         String customerSNo =           IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.getString("customerSNo", "null");
      Editor editor = IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putString("customerSNo", cusSno);
  editor.putString("customerPass", passcode);
             if (customerSNo.equals(cusSno)) {
              } else {
              editor.putBoolean("custSNoAuthStatus", false);
              }
            editor.commit();

Comment: don't do that..Initialize it in current class also..`SharedPreferences` are common in all classes wherever you are initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String CurrentString = "ABCD,EFGH";
String[] separated = CurrentString.split(",");
```

`separated[0];` // this will contain "ABCD"

`separated[1];` // this will contain "EFGH"

Comment: I Am splitting ABCDEFGHIJKLMN..i am doing like this String part1 scanResult.getContents().substring(0, 9), part2 = scanResult.getContents().substring(10);  splitting working...but J is not printing...

Comment: try this: String part1 = scanResult.getContents().substring(0, 10); String part2 =  scanResult.getContents().substring(10);